# Meaning of |-> 1[0:$] in assertions

Tags: system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

Usage example:

```
state==ACTIVE1 |-> 1[0:$] ##1 state==ACTIVE2
```

The problem the assertion is trying to solve is:
if the state machine reaches `state=ACTIVE1`, it will eventually reach `state=ACTIVE2`.

Any idea what `|-> 1[0:$]` actually means?

Also, is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SVA `1` is effectively a wildcard, because it is, by definition, true. So it matches anything.

`<expression>[<number or range>]` is the SVA repetition operator.

`$` means "infinity".

So, `1[0:$]` means "anything zero or more times".

Is there a better way to do it? Yes. Here are some other ways to do it that suffer all suffer from the same problems that your example does:

```
state==ACTIVE1 |-> ##[0:$] state==ACTIVE2
state==ACTIVE1 |-> eventually state==ACTIVE2
```

What are these problems?

(i) If there are lots of `ACTIVE1`s and no `ACTIVE2`s then more and more checks will be started (ie threads spawned), which slows down your simulation. This is a problem with the use of `$` or `eventually` on the right hand side (the *consequent* or *condition*).

(ii) Your assertion can never fail: it doesn't matter whether there has been no `ACTIVE2` by the heat death of the universe, your assertion will not fail. Here is a compromise assertion, a so-called *strong* property:

```
state==ACTIVE1 |-> s_eventually state==ACTIVE2
```

The `s_` stands for "strong". Now, if your assertion has not passed by the end of the simulation, that is considered  a fail.